Manjaro repo use inside Arch
I'm having issues with kernel 6.10.x with btrfs-cleaner and kswapd being 100% CPU each and the desktop freezing when it happens.
One bad thing about arch is that once a kernel is upgraded, I can't easily choose to stick to the older 6.9 series.
On Manjaro they have the linux69 and linux69-headers packages that would be a perfect fit.
Ideally, it would be nice to use Manjaro's repo straight for Arch.

It is actually simple. Just create a new pacman config file at /etc/pacman.manjaro.conf:
#
# /etc/pacman.conf
#
# See the pacman.conf(5) manpage for option and repository directives

[options]
HoldPkg     = pacman glibc
Architecture = auto
ParallelDownloads = 10

SigLevel = Optional TrustAll
LocalFileSigLevel = Optional

[core]
Server = https://manjaro.c3sl.ufpr.br/stable/$repo/$arch

[extra]
Server = https://manjaro.c3sl.ufpr.br/stable/$repo/$arch

[community]
Server = https://manjaro.c3sl.ufpr.br/stable/$repo/$arch

[multilib]
Server = https://manjaro.c3sl.ufpr.br/stable/$repo/$arch

#[chaotic-aur]
#Include = /etc/pacman.d/chaotic-mirrorlist

And then install linux69 and linux69-headers by switching to this config:
sudo pacman -Syy --config /etc/pacman.manjaro.conf linux69 linux69-headers

-yy options are required to ensure it doesn't use the cached repositories versions from the standard pacman.conf.
